# Мне необходимоСоставить программу для обработки массива из 12 вещественных чисел. и вывести нечетные числа, но выдает ошибку: тип real к integer

Tags: pascal

```
Program Massiv1;
Uses Crt;
var k:array[1..12] of real;
i,c:integer;
begin
clrscr;    
write('Введите элементы массива k:');
c:=0;  
for i:=1 to 12 do
begin 
readln(k[i]);
if (k[i] mod 2=0) then Inc(c);
end;
writeln;
writeln;  
for i:=1 to 12 do write(k[i]:4:4);
writeln;  
writeln('Количество нечетных элементов :',c); 
readkey;      
end.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

У вас массив k типа real (вещественные числа), операцию целочисленного деления mod можно использовать только с целыми числами.
Вам нужно заменить real на integer в 3 строчке.

Comment: Поскольку по условию задачи массив вещественный, то, вероятно, нужно брать целую часть `k[i]` (в Delphi, например, есть функция `Trunc`), а потом осуществлять проверку на чётность. Но не берусь оценить "идеологическую правильность" такого решения

Comment: Только сначала надо оценить дробность числа, т.к. дробное число чётным быть не может. Т.е. проверка должны быть типа `ki := Trunc(k[i]); if (ki = k[i]) and (ki mod 2 = 0) then ...`, где `ki: integer`. Единственно, я не помню как работает сравнение целого числа с вещественным, надо уточнить этот момент.